# frontend UI looks totally different and broken on heroku, how to fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon S3 buckets to store all of the applications assets, however, the app looks totally different in development than it does in production on heroku. Why might this be?

How can I get it to look the same? I've worked on several apps before and never experienced this issue. Any help would be great at this point!

production.rb:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :s3_credentials => {
          :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
          :region => ENV['REGION']
      }
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you define 'looks totally different' - as in no stylesheet? Or simply that uploaded assets are missing? Are you using different bucket names between dev and staging (I hope you are!)

Comment: Define "assets". That would generally refer to the asset pipeline—a problem with which would cause your lack of styling—but you've posted a paperclip config (where "assets" might mean "user uploads").

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

   or

bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

on your local code

Commit the changes and deploy to heroku

Comment: Precompiling locally requires to do that before every deploy. That's not a solution.

Comment: in productio.rb you can set config.assets.compile = true

Comment: and bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production is another way ,I know its not best practice.

Comment: the assets are precompiling, and in the same order as development. even after they are precompiled into one they still load as expected in the same order.